# NodeJS console log to ejs web page

Tags: node.js

Looking for way to show console log output into ejs webpage.

In case of output in console, I would like to view mirroring on the ejs page.

Comment: you need to forward same `message` which you have in `console.log(message)`, where message is `const message = \`show output...${result}\``; for example

Comment: Can you please separate code for JS file and EJS file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.